# Struct unpack MemoryError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, struct, binary

I'm triyng to read a image binary file into RAM with [struct unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). Binary file has 120MB and every pixel is represented by 16 bits.
For presition purposes later in computation, I need to cast 16 bit data into float64 numpy array...

According to my computation, I need in RAM 524MB to read all data. My PC has 8GB RAM and 4GB in free so I think that's not the problem.

I read here [Memory error](https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa/issues/88) in hgrecco's comment, maybe there is a struct unpack limit.

- So here is an extra question: What's that limit? It's no specified in official documentation....

Here is the code:

*PD: here nrows and ncols giving total image size is put as a default
parameter for simplicity:*

```
def read_BIL_img(filename, nrows = 8196, ncols = 8000):

    # Open and read entire BIL data into str type named "data"
    fi = open(filename, "rb")
    data = fi.read()
    fi.close()

    # Unpack all binary data into a flat tuple, accordint to a format defined.
    # It's read unsigned short integer as in https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#format-characters.
    format = "=%dH" % (int(nrows*ncols),)
    img_tuple = struct.unpack(format, data)

    # Convert flat tuple img into a numpy array of nrows*ncols.
    img_array = np.asarray(img_tuple).reshape((nrows, ncols))
    return img_array.astype(float)
```

I have the following error:

```
 img_tuple = struct.unpack(format, data)
 MemoryError
```

PD 2: I'm using python 2.7 interpreter and 1.9.2 numpy version in windows 10 machine.